# Enums with an underlying type of Byte fails in a switch

Tags: c#, .net, enums, switch-statement

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

> To declare an enum of another integral type, such as byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type, as shown in the following example.
>
> `enum Days : byte {Sat=1, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri};`

However, in my .NET 4.6 code

```
public enum MessageIdentifier : byte
{
    LaserRange = 0x50,
};

// ...more code

private void ParseMessage(byte[] fullPacket)
{
    switch (fullPacket[3])
    {
        case MessageIdentifier.LaserRange:
            // some wonderful code
            break;
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile.
**"Cannot convert expression of type 'MessageIdentifier' to type 'byte'.**

What's up? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try switching on `(MessageIdentifier)fullPacket[3]`

Comment: @Glorin: Make that an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `enum` declared with a different base type remains an `enum` - i.e. a separate type, not an alias for its base type. Among other things, it means that you need to perform all casts between the base type and the `enum` type *explicitly*. In other words, none of the following would compile:

```
MessageIdentifier a = (byte)0x50;      // Does not compile
byte b = MessageIdentifier.LaserRange; // Does not compile
```

In your situation it means that you need to add an explicit cast in front of `fullPacket[3]` expression.

**Note:** It looks like you are using the `enum` to decode messages sent around as bytes. In situations like that you would be better served with `byte`-typed *constants*, rather than enumerations:

```
static class MessageIdentifier {
    public const byte LaserRange = 0x50;
    ...
}
```

Now your code would compile without an explicit cast.

Answer (score 4):

While the underlying type is `byte`, in the higher level it's still an enumeration.

That is, you need an explicit conversion from `byte` to your enumeration type:

```
switch ((MessageIdentifier)fullPacket[3])
{
    case MessageIdentifier.LaserRange:
        // some wonderful code
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code below works. You need to cast your enum in the switch statement because you are not checking against an enum but rather a byte.

```
public enum MessageIdentifier : byte
{
    LaserRange = 0x50,
};

private static void ParseMessage(byte[] fullPacket)
{
    switch ((MessageIdentifier)fullPacket[3])
    {
        case MessageIdentifier.LaserRange:
            // some wonderful code
            break;
    }
}
```